# Sourcemap is not working using webpack to compile TS + Vue3

Tags: typescript, webpack, vuejs3, source-maps

I'm setting up a vue3+ts project with webpack and with my current config the build and webpack-dev-server works properly, but the **source map** for .vue files are now working, I can search the file in Chrome, but you just can't set any breakpoints.

- **webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode:'development',
  entry: './src/main.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'dist.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
   },
   module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: /\.vue$/,
            loader: 'vue-loader'
         },
         {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
               'style-loader',
               'css-loader'
            ]
         },
         {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            use: [
               {
                  loader: 'ts-loader',
                  options: {
                      configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, './tsconfig.json'),
                      appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
                  }  
               }
            ],
            exclude: /node_modules/,
          },
      ],
   },
   plugins: [
      new VueLoaderPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
         template: './index.html'
      })
   ],
   devtool: 'inline-source-map',
   devServer: {

    },
};
```

- **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ],
    },
    "types": [
      "node",
    ],
  },
  
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.js", 
    "src/**/*.ts", 
    "src/**/*.d.ts", 
    "src/**/*.tsx", 
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "docs/**/*.ts",
    "docs/**/*.vue",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
  ]
}
```

- **project structure**

[project folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ff6D.png)

I'm expecting that I can set the breakpoint correctly, and the breakpoint can be hit.

Comment: I'm also having this problem, exactly same thing, can see the file but not able to set any breakpoints